# Decoding a JSON object containing an array of variable type keyed off a type property and converting to a enum with associated values in swift 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, enums, decodable

Does someone know of a way to decode a JSON structure like this into a struct?

```
{"included": [
        {
            "type": "breeds",
            "id": "104",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Boxer"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/public/animals/breeds/104"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "colors",
            "id": "27",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Brindle with White"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/public/animals/colors/27"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "species",
            "id": "8",
            "attributes": {
                "singular": "Dog",
                "plural": "Dogs",
                "youngSingular": "Puppy",
                "youngPlural": "Puppies"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/public/animals/species/8"
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

The hard part is to handle the attributes property which can be a number of different enum values with different associated values depending on what the type property is set to.  I would like to store the attributes property as an enum with associated values which has this definition:

```
enum IncludedAttributes: Decodable {
    case breeds(name: String)
    case colors(name: String)
    case species(singular: String, plural: String, youngSingular: String, youngPlural: String)
    case statues(name: String, description: String)
    case locations(street: String, city: String, state: String, citystate: String, postalCode: String, country: String, phone: String, lat: String, lon: String, coordinates: String)
    case orgs(name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, postalcode: String, country: String, phone: String, email: String, url: String, facebookUrl: String, services: String, type: String, lat: String, lon: String, coordinates: String, citystate: String)
    case pictures(orginal: picture, large: picture, small: picture, order: Int, created: String, updated: String)
    case unknown
}
```

I need to look at the type property and create the appropriate attributes enum.  Does anyone please know how to do this in Swift 5?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I looked at the documentation and tried to find a web page which talks about this but nothing exactly describes a way to do this.  I know I need to handle two custom types one for where there is the array and another for the enumerated type but not sure how to do this.  Was thinking of just having one attributes struct with optionals and all properties but that seems hacky.

Comment: Looking at documentation and articles and thinking about some ideas isn't really the same thing as trying to solve a problem. Why don't you start designing and coding a solution and see how far you get yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I would organise `IncludedAttributes` differently using a collection of individual structs instead. The end result is very much the same but with `struct`s you can leverage compiler to generate the boilerplate for decoding the associated fields.

Basically all of it boils down to providing a custom implementation for `Decodable` protocol to handle different kinds of attributes, since the Swift compiler doesn't know the relationship between `type` and `attributes` fields.

First you can list all known types of items, i.e:

```
enum ItemType: String, Decodable {
    case breeds, colors, species
}
```

Then you can define the `AnyItem` type, where in place of `attributes` you can use a generic `Decodable` since this underlying type is picked up at runtime.

```
struct AnyItem: Decodable {
    var type: ItemType
    var id: String
    var attributes: Decodable

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, id, attributes
    }
}
```

The attributes can be represented by plain old `struct`s which conform to `Decodable`. Swift compiler will automatically generate the initialisers for them.

```
struct BreedAttributes: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct ColorAttributes: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct SpecieAttributes: Decodable {
    let singular: String
    let plural: String
    let youngSingular: String
    let youngPlural: String
}
```

Then implement a custom initialiser for `AnyItem`, which is trivial for the most part, except `attributes` which you have to handle based on the input `type`.

```
extension AnyItem {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.type = try container.decode(ItemType.self, forKey: .type)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

        switch self.type {
        case .breeds:
            self.attributes = try container.decode(BreedAttributes.self, forKey: .attributes)
        case .colors:
            self.attributes = try container.decode(ColorAttributes.self, forKey: .attributes)
        case .species:
            self.attributes = try container.decode(SpecieAttributes.self, forKey: .attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

and in order to access the correct `attributes` from the outside, you have to dynamically cast the attributes to the expected type, i.e:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let included: [AnyItem]
}

let json = "<YOUR JSON>"
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)

for item in response.included {
    switch item.type {
    case .breeds:
        if let attributes = item.attributes as? BreedAttributes {
            print("Got color attributes: \(attributes)")
        }

    case .colors:
        if let attributes = item.attributes as? ColorAttributes {
            print("Got color attributes: \(attributes)")
        }

    case .species:
        if let attributes = item.attributes as? SpecieAttributes {
            print("Got specie attributes: \(attributes)")
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, if you need to encode the same data back into the original hierarchy, implement `Encodable` protocol for all of the structs.

Complete playground code:
https://gist.github.com/pronebird/64334212b55db2dd3076a634208bbdad

Comment: Thanks for the help hpronebird!!!